# Unable to RETURN nodes after FOREACH in Neo4j Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We are creating a time tree, and this query here works:

```
CREATE (c:Century {century_label: 2000})
MATCH (c:Century {century_label: 2000})
WITH range(1900,1905) as YEARS, c
FOREACH (year in YEARS | CREATE (y:Year {year_label:year})-[r:YEAR_IN]->(c))
```

This one doesn't:

```
CREATE (c:Century {century_label: 2000})
MATCH (c:Century {century_label: 2000})
WITH range(1900,1905) as YEARS, c
FOREACH (year in YEARS | CREATE (y:Year {year_label:year})-[r:YEAR_IN]->(c))
RETURN y as YEAR
```

The problem is the `y as YEAR`, Neo4j throws an error about `y`, so it seems that you cannot do `FOREACH` and then collect the results after.

What is the proper syntax to return all the created nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer from the Neo4j Slack:

```
MATCH (c:Century {century_label:$century})
UNWIND range(1900,1999) as year
CREATE (y:Year {year_label:year})-[r:YEAR_IN]->(c)
RETURN y AS YEAR
```

Based on my reading as well, I believe this `UNWIND` is the successor to some of these more antiquated queries. I highly recommend gravitating towards unwind as much as possible.

We see the best performance with it in all tested cases so far.